# Calculate daily precipitation between 12pm and 12pm of the other day

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a .nc file that contains data every 1 hour of precipitation, my interest is to add the daily precipitation. But for this I have to take into account the precipitation between 12 pm on one day and 12 pm on the other, so I cannot apply "daysum" of cdo.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Previous answer seems applicable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946046/7017006

Comment: Correct Robert, that's the solution

Answer (score 1):

you can fudge it by shifting the time 12 hours, using daysum and then shifting it back:

```
cdo shifttime,12hours in.nc out1.nc 
cdo daysum out1.nc out2.nc 
cdo shifttime,-12hours out2.nc outer.nc
```

Using piping

```
cdo shifttime,-12hours -daysum -shifttime,12hours in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Hello Adrian, im here again. Now i have a .nc file that contains data every 6 hours of precipitation.  I need to change the shifttime command to 6 hours instead of 12 hours?